# How would I output the keys that have equivalent values across multiple dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given that I have 3 dictionaries, dicta, dictb, dictc, how would I form a dictionary, where the `key: value`  pairs are such that they can only be of keys that exist across all dictionaries, and values are equivalent?

Example:

```
dicta = {"one": "foo", "two": "bar", "three": "biz"}
dictb = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": "foo", "four": "foo"}
dictc = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": False, "five": "foo"}
```

And the result would be the following, since only one key value pair remained the same throughout all dicts:

```
{"two": "bar"}
```

Also, the "three dicts" example isn't exact. I may have three dicts, I may have two, I may have 10, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since dictionary keys are unique and hashable, and it looks like you have string values (which are hashable), you can simply find the intersection for all the `items`, and turn the resulting `set` into a `dict`:

```
result = dict(dicta.items() & dictb.items() & dictc.items())
```

Given your example data, `result` will be `{'two': 'bar'}`, as desired.

If you're using Python 2, use `viewitems()` instead of `items()`.

Comment: you don't need the `set` in front of each dictionary.  `a.items() & b.items() & c.items()` works the same way.

Comment: @KronoS: If you're in Python 3 you don't need it. In Python 2, you do (or you switch from `.items()` to `.viewitems()` which is equivalent in Python 2.7).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is set intersection of items from all the dicts.

```
a = set(dicta.items())
b = set(dictb.items())
c = set(dictc.items())
dict(a & b & c)
Out[7]: {'two': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work with any number of dicts:

```
>>> dicta = {"one": "foo", "two": "bar", "three": "biz"}
>>> dictb = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": "foo", "four": "foo"}
>>> dictc = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": False, "five": "foo"}
>>> dictlist = [dicta, dictb, dictc]
>>> items = set(dictlist[0].items())
>>> for thedict in dictlist[1:]:
...     items &= set(thedict.items())
... 
>>> result = dict(items)
>>> result
{'two': 'bar'}
```

**EDIT** As DSM points out below, you can use the fact that `set.intersection` takes multiple parameters to push the loop down into Python:

```
>>> dicta = {"one": "foo", "two": "bar", "three": "biz"}
>>> dictb = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": "foo", "four": "foo"}
>>> dictc = {"one": None, "two": "bar", "three": False, "five": "foo"}
>>> dict(set.intersection(*(set(x.items()) for x in (dicta, dictb, dictc))))
{'two': 'bar'}
```

Comment: The non-loop version might look something like `dict(set.intersection(*(set(d.items()) for d in dictlist)))`, although that looks more like `dicttuple`. :-)

Comment: Nitpicking here, but `dictlist` is actually a `tuple`.